# Configure x-export-frames to take svg screenshots (Mac/OSX)

Tags: init-file, osx

Using [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/idz35e/emacs_27_can_take_svg_screenshots_of_itself/g2c2c6y?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) as inspiration, I am trying to create a `screenshot-svg` command using the following config:

```lisp
(defun screenshot-svg ()
  "Save a screenshot of the current frame as an SVG image.
Saves to a temp file and puts the filename in the kill ring."
  (interactive)
  (let* ((filename (make-temp-file "Emacs" nil ".svg"))
         (data (x-export-frames nil 'svg)))
    (with-temp-file filename
      (insert data))
    (kill-new filename)
    (message filename)))
```

However, when I try to run the `screenshot-svg` command, I get the message `let*: Symbol’s function definition is void: x-export-frames`, and nothing seems to happen. How do I check if `x-export-frames` is available on my build? What do I need to do to get this working? Are there any other ways to get svg screenshots on emacs?

**EDIT:** I am using OSX, so I am also wondering if Cairo, or something similar is available for OSX?

Comment: How do do you check: do `M-x describe-function` (usually bound to `C-hf`) and see if `x-export-frames` offers anything.  What you need to do: compile emacs (version 27.1) with cairo support.

Comment: Thanks @FranBurstall - yes, I can now confirm that `x-export-frames` is not available on my system. I should have specified that I am running OSX (have updated question), and am trying to find out if it is possible to compile with cairo on OSX (or if there is an alternative)

Comment: You can check if the function is available using `(fboundp 'x-export-frames)`.  AFAIK there's no macOS build of Emacs with cairo.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2021-11-25 I only have sad news here:

While cairo works on macOS via `brew install cairo` just fine, I didn't find a way to make any of the Emacs builds aware of it. Tried `emacs-plus@28` and `emacs-head@28` and the [`build-emacs-for-macos`](https://github.com/jimeh/build-emacs-for-macos) script, but even with X11 support, the `x-export-frames` function isn't available.

Other `x-` prefixed functions exist, but no luck with the SVG saving thus far.